# Static files not found with Django/React app on AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy a Django/React app to AWS. I have an issue where the server isn't picking up the static files. I think I have configured everything correctly but doesn't show anything. I am not sure if I am missing a step because it seems to work correctly on PythonAnywhere but not AWS.

Here is my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I ran `python manage.py collectstatic` which generated my files to the root directory. It outputs `static files copied to '/home/ubuntu/test/test/static'`.

The error I get in the console is as follows `GET http://ec2-18-217-253-182.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/static/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I am hoping someone has had this same issue because the several other solutions on SO haven't solved the problem. This is the file structure currently

```
test/
├── test/
├── frontend/
└── static/
```

Comment: Have you specified `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your settings?

Comment: if your static files are stored locally why is your frontend calling aws?

Comment: Is this AWS S3?

Comment: How are you running your Django project? Is there any HTTP server like nginx or apache in between your project and internet?

Comment: @dan-klasson its referring and ec2 instance

Comment: I don't know what that means but you might want to look at `STATICFILES_STORAGE` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-cloud-service-or-cdn

Comment: @xxbinxx Yes I am using NGINX

Comment: @dan-klasson I am using ec2 not s3

Comment: @User123 have you specified /static path in your nginx ?

Comment: can you check and  confirm if you have something like this in your nginx conf
`location /static/ {
        alias   /home/ubuntu/test/test/static/;
    }` ?
also is your server serving media files properly ??

Comment: No @xxbinxx Do I also need to restart NGINX?

Comment: Yes you need to restart it if you make a change to the nginx config file

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189173/xxbinxx-xk0nb1n-solutions join here

Answer (score -3):

Did you use Create React App? If so you will have to configure [your `PUBLIC_URL`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration) to point to the correct folder.

Since I don't know you exact Django set up, here are a few other things to consider:

**Correct URL (2.1 syntax)**

```
urlpatterns += [
    re_path(r'(?P<path>.*)', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='home')
]
```

**Correct static files URL:**

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'media'
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR.parent / 'build' / 'static']
```

**Correct S3 Bucket configuration:**

```
# utils.py
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


def StaticRootS3BotoStorage(): return S3Boto3Storage(location='static')


def MediaRootS3BotoStorage(): return S3Boto3Storage(location='media')
```

and

```
# conf.py

import os

from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured


def get_env_variable(var_name):
    """Get the environment variable or return exception."""
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = 'Set the {} environment variable'.format(var_name)
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = get_env_variable("ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = get_env_variable("SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = get_env_variable("AWS_BUCKET_NAME")
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'

STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.settings.aws.utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.settings.aws.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'
```

For reference this is the folder setup that I use (in case you struggle with the paths). Inside `aws` are `conf.py` and `utils.py`.

[image]

Comment: No I didn't use create-react-app